# Bookmarking of tabs using Ext JS?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, tabpanel

Need some help with *bookmarking of tabs* in Ext jS.

I have a tab panel containing multiple tabs and clicking individual tabs changes the URL. I'm currently using hash. However,  I couldn't restore the app back when I use its " *id + delimiter + other id's*" URL to navigate to the page directly.

Here is the sample code:

```
launch : function() {
    Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(new Ext.state.CookieProvider(
            {
                expires : new Date(new Date().getTime()
                        + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7))
            }));

var  tabPanel=new Ext.TabPanel({
    width:1000,
    title:'TabPanel',
    height:700,
    id:'main-tab',
    activeTab:0,
    layout:'fit',       
    region:'north', 
    stateful:true,
    stateId:'tp1',
    stateEvents:['tabchange'],
    getState:function(){
        return {
            activeTab:this.items.findIndex('id',this.getActiveTab().id)             
        };
    },
    applyState:function(s){
        this.setActiveTab(s.activeTab);
    },
    items:
        [
          //included tabID and title
         ],
     listeners:{            
                tabchange:function(tabPanel,currTab){                                       
                    window.location.hash='#myTabs/'+currTab.id; //config.position;
                    console.log(window.location);                   
                }
        }
});

var viewport=new Ext.Viewport({
    id:'main-viewport',     
    layout : 'fit',
    title:'Main',
    deferredRender:true,
    items : [ tabPanel ],
    width:200,
    region:'west'
});

viewport.doLayout();
```

I have solved the problem currently by saving the current state of the page using the `expire` config (using `Ext.state.Manager` and `Ext.state.CookieProvider`).

However, the url I use should be **valid for over any length of time**.

Also, when if I last visited URL is *.../apps/Bookmarking/services.html#myTabs/5*
and I chnage my URL back to *.../apps/Bookmarking/services.html*, it should go back to my default (first in my case) tab. Instead it navigates back to *.../apps/Bookmarking/services.html#myTabs/5*.

How can I rectify that ?

Thanks in advance!

PS: Please check this link for the entire set of changes I've made for this problem
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?154174-Bookmarking-and-History-in-extjs

Comment: I tried implementing the concept using `Ext.util.History` feature, However, I'm unable to bookmark the tabs . Example : http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/history/history.html#main-tabs:tab4 should jump to **Tab 4** but it retraces back to the **Tab 1:subtab 1** .

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track looking at [Ext.util.History](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.util.History). Unfortunatly I think you have just found a bug in [their example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/history/history.html#main-tabs%3atab4).

Rather than always setting the active tab after render;

```
function onAfterRender() {
    ...

    var activeTab1 = Ext.getCmp('main-tabs').getActiveTab(),
        activeTab2 = activeTab1.getActiveTab();

    onTabChange(activeTab1, activeTab2);
}
```

Maybe attempt to set it if there is no token present;

```
Ext.util.History.on('ready', function(history){
    if ( !history.getToken() ) {
        var activeTab1 = Ext.getCmp('main-tabs').getActiveTab(),
            activeTab2 = activeTab1.getActiveTab();

        onTabChange(activeTab1, activeTab2);
    }
}, this);
```